# Altering Stored Procedure with if then Statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, alter

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE usp_remove_vendor
    @Vendor varchar(50)
    AS
    DECLARE 
    @vendorid  char(10);
    BEGIN  SET @vendorid = (SELECT vend_id FROM vendors WHERE vend_name = @Vendor );
    DELETE from  products where vend_id =@vendorid;
    DELETE from vendors where vend_id =@vendorid;
    END
```

I need help altering the statementverify if the vendor name (@vname) in the parameter is even in the list of vendors. Modify so  IF the vendor is in the system, remove them, ELSE you want to display a message 'Vendor not found' aka (IF THEN statement)

To determine if the local variable is empty or not, consider looking at it's length (Lookup the reference for LEN() - note if you prefer to do it differently that's fine too.
Use PRINT to output 'Vendor not found'

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_remove_vendor
    @Vendor varchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @vendorid  char(10), @result NVARCHAR(50);
        SELECT @vendorid=vend_id FROM vendors WHERE vend_name = @Vendor;

        IF @vendorid IS NULL OR @vendorid=''
        BEGIN
            SET @result='Vendor not found'
            print 'Vendor not found'
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN

            DELETE from  products where vend_id =@vendorid;
            DELETE from vendors where vend_id =@vendorid;
            SET @result='Vendor deleted successfully.'
        END
        SELECT 'Result'=@result

    END
```

**Explanation**
I have used Result variable to return the result whether the vendor was found or not?